# Variables in Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing a PHP script in which i need to run a MySQL query. I opened the data connection and all such pleasantries are working fine. My only doubt is regarding the syntax of the following query, since it is not working. I have a php variable $post_id against which I am selecting from the database.

```
$query1="SELECT needer FROM needer_blood WHERE value_id='$post_id'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$req_id=$result[0];
```

Comment: You're not getting the result, see [mysqli_fetch_object](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_object), for example.  FYI: `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: dont use $post_id directly in query, use sql injection.

Comment: @Zeeshan i guess you meant "**that's** sql injection"... :)

Comment: **Read This >>** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not fetching the result.

So try this

```
<?php

$query1="SELECT needer FROM needer_blood WHERE value_id='$post_id'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['needer'];//You can display your result like this. 
}
```

Also mysql is depricated learn Mysqli or PDO.

For Mysqli function check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

For PDO function check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Thanks buddy. I mean, the syntax "SELECT needer FROM needer_blood WHERE value_id='$post_id'";
 is right. isnt it? with the $post_id variable in it.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, its better approach if you user [SQL INJECTION](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
<?php

$query1="SELECT needer FROM needer_blood WHERE value_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($post_id)."'";

$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); // die only used in development , remove when you live this

$data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

echo $req_id = $data['needer']; // $req_id = $data[0];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, notice that your query variable is called $query1 and your mysql_query is using a variable called $query (variable mismatch?).

You can use mysql_fetch_assoc() to get an associative array from your query.

Using the following code should work, though you should do some checking to make sure that the $result[0] exists.

```
// Query String
$query1="SELECT needer FROM needer_blood WHERE value_id='$post_id'";
// Run the query
$result=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
// Fetch Associative Array
$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
// Get result [0]: this could result in an error if your query result is empty.
$req_id=$rows[0];
```

Also, as others have pointed out, mysql is deprecated and you should update to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) if your server supports it.  If not, change servers.

Also, as others pointed out, you should watch out for SQL injection.  [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) adresses the issue well.